# Make the table look better

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs

I am trying to create an appealing table. So far this is my result:

[image: The current table]

As you can see the table does not look right. For example the work `Komplexität` is not hyphenated right. And the column titles `Kriterien` and `Gewichtungsfaktor` are not on the same line as the rest of the column titles.

Has somebody a tip how to fix those mistakes, or how to convert the whole table to a `booktabs` table?

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    titlepage=firstiscover
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
onehalfspacing
]{setspace}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setmainlanguage{german}

% rotate text in table heads
\newcommand\rotateText[2]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#2cm}{\raggedright#1}}}

% Tabularx cells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\hyphenation{Um-setz-bar-keit Kom-ple-xi-tät}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{0.1}L{0.39}C{0.06}|C{0.06}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}}C{0.06}|C{0.06}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}}C{0.06}|C{0.06}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}}C{0.06}|C{0.06}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}}C{0.06}}
            & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotateText{\textbf{Kriterien}}{4}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotateText{\textbf{Gewichtungsfaktor}}{4}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{RSS}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{FP}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Prox.}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Opt.}} \\
            & & & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} \\
            \toprule
            \multirow{3}{*}{\rotateText{Komplexität}{1.75}} & Installationsaufwand & 4 & 4 & 16 & 2 & 8 & 3 & 12 & 5 & 20 \\
            & Hardware & 2 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 \\
            & Software & 2 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{3}{*}{\rotateText{Kosten}{0.5}} & Installation & 2 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 \\
            & Anzahl Sensoren & 4 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 \\
            \midrule
            & Energieverbrauch & 4 & 3 & 12 & 3 & 12 & 4 & 16 & 5 & 20 \\
            \\[-1em]
            & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Punkte} & 62 & & 58 & & 66 & & 90 \\
            & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Wirtschaftliche Wertigkeit} & 0.69 & & 0.64 & & 0.73 & & 1 \\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is Komplexität not hyphenated right? You gave a too wide width...

Comment: And please do not load booktabs if you ignore all advice the manual tries to give. Your table won't look better with booktabs rules and vertical lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend thinking twice about the use of colour and actually making use of the facilities of `booktabs`.

Consider as a starting point (or if @TeXnician's changes in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398985/59848) - which admittedly look better - are too radical):
[image]

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    titlepage=firstiscover
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setmainlanguage{german}

% rotate text in table heads
\newcommand\rotateText[2]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#2cm}{\raggedright#1}}}

% Tabularx cells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\hyphenation{Um-setz-bar-keit Kom-ple-xi-tät}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
            C{0.1}%
            L{0.39}%
            C{0.06}%
            C{0.06}%
            C{0.06}%
            C{0.06}%
            C{0.06}%
            C{0.06}%
            C{0.06}%
            C{0.06}%
            C{0.06}%
        }
            \toprule
            & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotateText{\textbf{Kriterien}}{3.8}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotateText{\textbf{Gewichtungsfaktor}}{3.8}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{RSS}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{FP}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Prox.}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Opt.}} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
            & & & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{3}{*}{\rotateText{Komplexität}{1.4}} & Installationsaufwand & 4 & 4 & 16 & 2 & 8 & 3 & 12 & 5 & 20 \\
            & Hardware & 2 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 \\
            & Software & 2 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 \\
            \cmidrule(lr){1-11}
            \multirow{3}{*}{\rotateText{Kosten}{0.4}} & Installation & 2 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 \\
            & Anzahl Sensoren & 4 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 \\
            \cmidrule(lr){1-11}
            & Energieverbrauch & 4 & 3 & 12 & 3 & 12 & 4 & 16 & 5 & 20 \\
            \midrule
            & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Punkte} & 62 & & 58 & & 66 & & 90 \\
            & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Wirtschaftliche Wertigkeit} & 0.69 & & 0.64 & & 0.73 & & 1 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I like this layout as it preserves more of the basic structure, but manual factors are horrible (or spooky as it's Halloween)...

Comment: @TeXnician 1st: agreed manual factors are horrible - some could be weeded out here. 2nd: on consideration, I find your layout more logical, with the 'summary' columns appearing more naturally to the right.

Answer (score 3):

what is fancy and what is aesthetic (regarding table design) ... is very personal opinions :-), so i only rewrote your code to be more simple and gives similar result obtained with yours *mwe*:

[image]

(red lines indicate text margins). in *mwe* below is used `makecell` package for column headers, `booktabs` only for determine `\cmidrule`, determination of columns is simplified, etc

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    titlepage=firstiscover
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\hyphenation{Um-setz-bar-keit Kom-ple-xi-tät}
%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Gewichtungsfaktor }
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}        l l
                                        c c
    >{\columncolor{gray!10}\centering}  X c
    >{\columncolor{gray!10}\centering}  X c
    >{\columncolor{gray!10}\centering}  X c
    >{\columncolor{gray!10}[\tabcolsep][0pt]\centering\arraybackslash}  X
                            @{}}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    &   &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{RSS}}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{FP}}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Prox.}}
                        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Opt.}}                       \\
    \cmidrule(l{2.5pt}){4-5}
    \cmidrule(l{2.5pt}){6-7}
    \cmidrule(l{2.5pt}){8-9}
    \cmidrule(l{2.5pt}){10-11}
    &   \rothead{\textbf{Kriterien}}
        &   \rothead{\textbf{Gewichtungsfaktor}}
            &   \rothead{Erfüllungsgrad}
                &   \rothead{Werte}
                    &   \rothead{Erfüllungsgrad}
                        &   \rothead{Werte}
                            &   \rothead{Erfüllungsgrad}
                                &   \rothead{Werte}
                                    &   \rothead{Erfüllungsgrad}
                                        &   \rothead{Werte}                         \\
    \Xhline{0.75pt}
\thead[l]{Komplexität}
    &   Installationsaufwand    & 4 & 4 & 16    & 2 &  8    & 3 & 12    & 5 & 20    \\
    &   Hardware                & 2 & 4 &  8    & 4 &  8    & 4 &  8    & 5 & 10    \\
    &   Software                & 2 & 4 &  8    & 3 &  6    & 5 & 10    & 5 & 10    \\
    \hline
\thead[l]{Kosten}
    &   Installation            & 2 & 3 &  6    & 2 &  4    & 4 &  8    & 5 & 10    \\
    &   Anzahl Sensoren         & 4 & 3 &  6    & 2 &  4    & 4 &  8    & 5 & 10    \\
    &   Energieverbrauch        & 4 & 3 & 12    & 3 & 12    & 4 & 16    & 5 & 20    \\

    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Punkte}        & 62    &   & 58    &   & 66    &   & 90    \\
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Wirtschaftliche Wertigkeit}
                                        & 0.69  &   & 0.64  &   & 0.73  &   & 1     \\
    \Xhline{0.75pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**edit:** after reading [TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician) comment i see that above *mwe* wasn't complete. now i correct this. in correction i consider mentioned comment too.

Comment: Do you really think that "Gewichtungsfaktor" belogs to RSS?

Comment: @TeXnician, no, i haven't any clue about meaning of tables content :-(. it should be simple to exclude it with change `\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){3-5}` to `\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){4-5}`. now this seems this more logical to me too :-). i will correct this asap and also add missing code (copy-past problem).

Answer (score 2):

I would swap columns and rows and start to utilize `booktabs` as well as `rotating`. As a starter:

[image: table]

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    titlepage=firstiscover
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
onehalfspacing
]{setspace}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setmainlanguage{german}

% rotate text in table heads
\newcommand\rotateText[2]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#2cm}{\raggedright#1}}}

% Tabularx cells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\hyphenation{Um-setz-bar-keit Kom-ple-xi-tät}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{0.1}L{0.39}C{0.06}|C{0.06}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}}C{0.06}|C{0.06}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}}C{0.06}|C{0.06}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}}C{0.06}|C{0.06}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}}C{0.06}}
            & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotateText{\textbf{Kriterien}}{4}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotateText{\textbf{Gewichtungsfaktor}}{4}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{RSS}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{FP}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Prox.}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Opt.}} \\
            & & & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} & \rotateText{Erfüllungsgrad}{3.18} & \rotateText{Werte}{3.18} \\
            \toprule
            \multirow{3}{*}{\rotateText{Komplexität}{1.75}} & Installationsaufwand & 4 & 4 & 16 & 2 & 8 & 3 & 12 & 5 & 20 \\
            & Hardware & 2 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 \\
            & Software & 2 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{3}{*}{\rotateText{Kosten}{0.5}} & Installation & 2 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 \\
            & Anzahl Sensoren & 4 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 \\
            \midrule
            & Energieverbrauch & 4 & 3 & 12 & 3 & 12 & 4 & 16 & 5 & 20 \\
            \\[-1em]
            & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Punkte} & 62 & & 58 & & 66 & & 90 \\
            & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Wirtschaftliche Wertigkeit} & 0.69 & & 0.64 & & 0.73 & & 1 \\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

        \begin{sidewaystable}
            \centering
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{8}{X}}
                \toprule & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Komplexität} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kosten} & & &\\\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
                Produkt & Installationsaufwand (4) & Hardware (2) & Software (2) & Installation (2) & Anzahl Sensoren (4) & Energieverbrauch (4) & Punkte & Wirtsch. Wertigkeit\\\midrule
                RSS\\
                \hskip.5em Erfüllungsgrad & 4 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 3 & &\\
                \hskip.5em Werte & 16 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 12 & 62 & 0.69\\\addlinespace
                RSS\\
                \hskip.5em Erfüllungsgrad & 4 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 3 & &\\
                \hskip.5em Werte & 16 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 12 & 62 & 0.69\\\addlinespace
                RSS\\
                \hskip.5em Erfüllungsgrad & 4 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 3 & &\\
                \hskip.5em Werte & 16 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 12 & 62 & 0.69\\\bottomrule
            \end{tabularx}\medbreak
            Zahlen in Klammern bezeichnen die Gewichtungsfaktoren der einzelnen Komponenten zur Gesamtpunktzahl.
        \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks great!!!!

Comment: It looks great :) but I am not sure if we are allowed to put a table sideways.